# Split column that contains two values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a similar dataframe to the next one:

| Names | Case type | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Patrick | Email | 10 |
| James | Phone | 78 |
| Kerstin | Email | 50 |
| James | Email | 69 |
| Patrick | Phone | 48 |
| Kerstin | Phone | 42 |

My idea is to expand Case type into another column so that each agent has email and phone assigned to their names and it only appears one:

| Names | Type 1 | Number | Type 2 | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kerstin | Email | 50 | Phone | 42 |
| James | Email | 69 | Phone | 78 |
| Patrick | Email | 10 | Phone | 48 |

So far, I have tried using .groupby('Names') but this does not seem to work at all.

Is there anything that can be done? Another idea I had was to sort things by name and then split the dataframe into two dataframe and then merge them by agent? But it seems like there's something that could work better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, this could be a better representation?

```
>>> df.pivot(index='Names', columns='Case type', values='Number')

Case type  Email  Phone
Names
James         69     78
Kerstin       50     42
Patrick       10     48
```

In your idea, you can't distinguish email `Number` from phone.